# set the results of facebook integration to labels

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, swift3, facebook-sdk-4.x

Im working on a project in Swift 3.0 and I have an authentication sign up procedure using Facebook. So basically I've done the FB integration part and once logged in to an account as a result I'm getting the user's email address, name,Id and the url of the profile pic as bellow since i have requested them (this is what I get in my console). The format that I receive as bellow.

```
Optional({
    email = "xxxxx@yahoo.com";
    id = xxxxxxxxxx;
    name = "xxxxxx xxxx";
    picture =     {
        data =         {
            "is_silhouette" = 0;
            url = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1-1/c2.0.50.50/p50x50/10441341_10201209786847369_5426097469926927988_n.jpg?oh=1b4d8709be17338bc7e877d411b96eee&oe=58CE5B13";
        };
    };
})
```

My requirement is to assign these email, name, id field in to labels and print them out.

The code of my relevant view controller as bellow. What should I add ??

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var displayLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        view.addSubview(loginButton)
        //frame's are obselete, please use constraints instead because its 2016 after all
        loginButton.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 50, width: view.frame.width - 32, height: 50)

       loginButton.delegate = self
        loginButton.readPermissions = ["email", "public_profile"]

    }
    func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        print("Did log out of facebook")
    }

  @IBAction func loginButtonPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        FBSDKLoginManager().logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: self) { (result, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print("Custom FB Login failed:", err)
                return
            }
            print("FB login Sucess")
            print(result?.token.tokenString)



            self.showEmailAddress()
        }
    }

    func showEmailAddress() {
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, email,picture"]).start { (connection, result, err) in

            if err != nil {
                print("Failed to start graph request:", err)
                return
            }
            print(result)

//            self.displayLabel.text = result["email"]as? NSMutableArray
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `result["email"]as? NSMutableArray` why as NSMutableArray? `as String`, no?

Comment: despite of what you put it gives an error message saying 'Type Any has no subscription members'. Thats why I have commented that line sir. Just wants to assign that result to the label as i have tried and failed

Comment: You have to tell the compiler, that `result` is a dictionary (in our case: `[String:Any]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First specify the type of your result object to `[String: Any]` and then get value from it.

```
if let dic = result as? [String: Any] {
    self.displayLabel.text = dic["email"] as? String
    self.displayNameLabel.text = dic["name"] as? String
    self.displayIdLabel.text = dic["id"] as? String
}
```